# How to use Seekbar in setting?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, android-seekbar

I want to use Seekbar in setting to choose number 1 to 10. Is there any way to do this? I extend `PreferenceActivity` for my setting activity.

As I found from [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/), but I don't know how to create Seekbar inside of the `PreferenceScreen`. Thank in advance.
Here is activity

```
 public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);    }
}
```

And setting.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_user_profile" >

        <EditTextPreference

                android:title="@string/pref_user_name"

                android:summary="@string/pref_user_name_summary"

                android:key="prefUsername"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

     

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_update_setting" >

        <CheckBoxPreference

            android:defaultValue="false"

            android:key="prefSendReport"

            android:summary="@string/pref_send_report_summary"

            android:title="@string/pref_send_report" >

        </CheckBoxPreference>

 

        <ListPreference

            android:key="prefSyncFrequency"

            android:entries="@array/syncFrequency"

            android:summary="@string/pref_sync_frequency_summary"

            android:entryValues="@array/syncFrequencyValues"

            android:title="@string/pref_sync_frequency" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

 

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Please edit your question to add codes.

Comment: I am not used to use tool.Some code are not appear in question.All I write is downloaded from above link.So,you can check it in the link.Sorry about that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't mind using the Android.Support.v7.Preference Library, then you can use [SeekBarPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SeekBarPreference.html).

You could then use in XML:

```
<SeekBarPreference
            android:key="keyName"
            android:title="Property Label"
            android:summary="Summary."
            android:max="5"
            android:defaultValue="0" />
```

Comment: This is not a `DialogPreference` variant, means it will show the seek bar where the `<SeekBarPreference/>` tag located at the view hierarchy rather than inside a `DialogPreference`.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no SeekBarPreference out of the box, though I have seen some official source code.
Maybe you want to use this library:   https://github.com/MrBIMC/MaterialSeekBarPreference